# Amazon advertising API sponsored brands ( /sb/ previously /hsa/)

Tags: api, amazon-advertising-api

I am following the [official documentation](https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/sponsored-brands/3-0/openapi#/Campaigns) and I can see that sponsored brands has the following endpoint: https://advertising-api-test.amazon.com/v2/sb/campaigns (I suppose it was https://advertising-api-test.amazon.com/v2/hsa/campaigns in the past)

When I make the API call I get:

> {"code":"NOT_FOUND","details":"Could not find resource for full path:
>   https://advertising-api-test.amazon.com/v1/sb/campaigns","requestId":"xxxx"}

I tried different endpoints: /v3/sb/campaigns, /sb/campaigns but I still have the same response.

Is the official documentation wrong ? I do get a response when I use /hsa/ but I only get the old API version like when I try to create a campaign I get:

> {"code":"405","details":"No resource method found for POST, return 405
>   with Allow header","requestId":"xxxx"}

Comment: /sb/campaigns without the version should work

Comment: ah, i forgot i was told from Amazon Support in November 2019 that:
"Sandbox environment for Sponsored Brands campaigns is not currently available for testing. This is in our backlog but not prioritized at the moment. It is recommended to test the functionality on existing campaigns such as list operations."

Comment: Thanks! Even getting an answer from their support is slow! I appreciate saving me the time.

Comment: @tector do you have an idea about sponsored display as well ? even without sandbox I still get : {"code":"NOT_FOUND","details":"Could not find resource for full path: https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/sd/campaigns","requestId":"xxxxx"}

Comment: Yes, i got the info from technical support just one week ago that API access for Sponsored Display Campaigns is still beta and currently only available on the NA region. Currently not available in EU and no sandbox at all. :-(

Comment: They really should mention this on their website! Okey thank :)

Comment: i try this  `https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa/sd/campaigns`  to get campaigns records gave me error 403

Comment: @AmitNayek you should use this endpoint https://advertising-api.amazon.com/sd/campaigns

Comment: Hi all, related to sponsored brands api, do you have any idea on how to filter Sponsored Brands reports filtered by a product? https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reference/sponsored-brands/2/reports I meant the post request `/v2/hsa/{recordType}/report`